# MySQL query for custom search engine question

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having two issues, this is the query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT *, SUM(MATCH(title, beskrivelse) AGAINST('$input' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as score
    FROM search_posts
    WHERE MATCH(title, beskrivelse) AGAINST('$input' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    GROUP BY title, beskrivelse
    ORDER BY score DESC";
```

first issue, if I start out the query with a + or - sign, or do eg. "gold +" as query, I get fatal error:

> syntax error, unexpected $end

How do I filter it so it won't make errors but allow the signs?.

second issue, if I have this word in database "Gold digger", and a lot of others then I search "g" and get a lot then "go" get nothing, then "gol" and maybe find one, then "gold" and finally get it, how do i modify this so it will show it and never return 0?

I tried adding %{$input}% but changed nothing, also modified mysql.ini and added

```
innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
ft_min_word_len=1
ft_stopword_file=""
```

and rebuild the fulltext index, but didn't change anything.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please add table schema. You should strip the special characters or escape them. I would strip them as a I dont think they are even indexed, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/248607/which-characters-are-considered-word-characters

Comment: using PHP variables directly in the sql is opening your app to sql injection - you ought to use a prepared statement

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Yeah im gonna rewrite to use PDO and preparedstatement i can see, but i think what i really wanted this to do, is search ala google where it takes the search word and if its matches beginning of a word its rated high, if its beginning of children words it gets ranked medium, and part of word it gets ranket low (and of course views ect)..

As it is now people have to write the excact word to get a match, which isnt good.

I guess this would require multiple queries or a keywords table, and cant be done with a query like mine?.